MongoDB no logra correr el servidor
Saludos estoy instalando MongoDB en mi PC pero no logro que corra el servidor.
Lo que he hecho:

Ejecutar el instalador e instalar tambien MongoDB Compass
Crear la carpeta c:/data/db y c:/data/log
Poner la variable de ambiente en Windows
El archivo mongod.cfg tiene la ruta respectiva de las carpetas c:/data/db
Le di todos los permisos a la carpeta bin
El servicio de mongodb para que se inicie con Windows está en automático pero si trato de iniciarlo me generar error


Este es el resultado al ejecutar: mongod
{"t":{"$date":"2024-11-09T13:49:02.677-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":5945603, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Multi threading initialized"}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-11-09T13:49:02.677-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648601, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen unavailable. If TCP FastOpen is required, set at least one of the related parameters","attr":{"relatedParameters":["tcpFastOpenServer","tcpFastOpenClient","tcpFastOpenQueueSize"]}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-11-09T13:49:02.681-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915701, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Initialized wire specification","attr":{"spec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":25},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":25},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":6,"maxWireVersion":25},"isInternalClient":true}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-11-09T13:49:02.682-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"TENANT_M", "id":7091600, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Starting TenantMigrationAccessBlockerRegistry"}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-11-09T13:49:02.682-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":10384,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/data/db","architecture":"64-bit","host":"PRINCIPAL"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-11-09T13:49:02.682-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23398,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Target operating system minimum version","attr":{"targetMinOS":"Windows 7/Windows Server 2008 R2"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-11-09T13:49:02.682-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"8.0.3","gitVersion":"89d97f2744a2b9851ddfb51bdf22f687562d9b06","modules":[],"allocator":"tcmalloc-gperf","environment":{"distmod":"windows","distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-11-09T13:49:02.683-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Microsoft Windows 10","version":"10.0 (build 19045)"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-11-09T13:49:02.683-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-11-09T13:49:02.686-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22315,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Opening WiredTiger","attr":{"config":"create,cache_size=3549M,session_max=33000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,remove=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),builtin_extension_config=(zstd=(compression_level=6)),file_manager=(close_idle_time=600,close_scan_interval=10,close_handle_minimum=2000),statistics_log=(wait=0),json_output=(error,message),verbose=[recovery_progress:1,checkpoint_progress:1,compact_progress:1,backup:0,checkpoint:0,compact:0,evict:0,history_store:0,recovery:0,rts:0,salvage:0,tiered:0,timestamp:0,transaction:0,verify:0,log:0],prefetch=(available=true,default=false),"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-11-09T13:49:02.707-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"WTRECOV",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":{"ts_sec":1731174542,"ts_usec":706631,"thread":"10384:140731303942288","session_name":"txn-recover","category":"WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS","category_id":34,"verbose_level":"DEBUG_1","verbose_level_id":1,"msg":"Recovering log 7 through 8"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-11-09T13:49:02.812-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"WTRECOV",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":{"ts_sec":1731174542,"ts_usec":811626,"thread":"10384:140731303942288","session_name":"txn-recover","category":"WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS","category_id":34,"verbose_level":"DEBUG_1","verbose_level_id":1,"msg":"Recovering log 8 through 8"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-11-09T13:49:02.947-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"WTRECOV",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":{"ts_sec":1731174542,"ts_usec":946625,"thread":"10384:140731303942288","session_name":"txn-recover","category":"WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS","category_id":34,"verbose_level":"DEBUG_1","verbose_level_id":1,"msg":"Main recovery loop: starting at 7/384 to 8/256"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-11-09T13:49:03.154-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"WTRECOV",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":{"ts_sec":1731174543,"ts_usec":153627,"thread":"10384:140731303942288","session_name":"txn-recover","category":"WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS","category_id":34,"verbose_level":"DEBUG_1","verbose_level_id":1,"msg":"Recovering log 7 through 8"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-11-09T13:49:03.269-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"WTRECOV",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":{"ts_sec":1731174543,"ts_usec":269562,"thread":"10384:140731303942288","session_name":"txn-recover","category":"WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS","category_id":34,"verbose_level":"DEBUG_1","verbose_level_id":1,"msg":"Recovering log 8 through 8"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-11-09T13:49:03.369-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"WTRECOV",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":{"ts_sec":1731174543,"ts_usec":369559,"thread":"10384:140731303942288","session_name":"txn-recover","category":"WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS","category_id":34,"verbose_level":"DEBUG_1","verbose_level_id":1,"msg":"recovery log replay has successfully finished and ran for 663 milliseconds"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-11-09T13:49:03.370-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"WTRECOV",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":{"ts_sec":1731174543,"ts_usec":369559,"thread":"10384:140731303942288","session_name":"txn-recover","category":"WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS","category_id":34,"verbose_level":"DEBUG_1","verbose_level_id":1,"msg":"Set global recovery timestamp: (0, 0)"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-11-09T13:49:03.370-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"WTRECOV",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":{"ts_sec":1731174543,"ts_usec":370557,"thread":"10384:140731303942288","session_name":"txn-recover","category":"WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS","category_id":34,"verbose_level":"DEBUG_1","verbose_level_id":1,"msg":"Set global oldest timestamp: (0, 0)"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-11-09T13:49:03.414-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"WTRECOV",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":{"ts_sec":1731174543,"ts_usec":414558,"thread":"10384:140731303942288","session_name":"txn-recover","category":"WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS","category_id":34,"verbose_level":"DEBUG_1","verbose_level_id":1,"msg":"recovery rollback to stable has successfully finished and ran for 44 milliseconds"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-11-09T13:49:03.482-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"WTCHKPT",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":{"ts_sec":1731174543,"ts_usec":481558,"thread":"10384:140731303942288","session_name":"WT_SESSION.checkpoint","category":"WT_VERB_CHECKPOINT_PROGRESS","category_id":7,"verbose_level":"DEBUG_1","verbose_level_id":1,"msg":"saving checkpoint snapshot min: 1, snapshot max: 1 snapshot count: 0, oldest timestamp: (0, 0) , meta checkpoint timestamp: (0, 0) base write gen: 20"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-11-09T13:49:03.488-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"WTRECOV",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":{"ts_sec":1731174543,"ts_usec":488753,"thread":"10384:140731303942288","session_name":"txn-recover","category":"WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS","category_id":34,"verbose_level":"DEBUG_1","verbose_level_id":1,"msg":"recovery checkpoint has successfully finished and ran for 8 milliseconds"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-11-09T13:49:03.489-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"WTRECOV",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":{"ts_sec":1731174543,"ts_usec":488753,"thread":"10384:140731303942288","session_name":"txn-recover","category":"WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS","category_id":34,"verbose_level":"DEBUG_1","verbose_level_id":1,"msg":"recovery was completed successfully and took 783ms, including 663ms for the log replay, 44ms for the rollback to stable, and 8ms for the checkpoint."}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-11-09T13:49:03.494-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4795906, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger opened","attr":{"durationMillis":808}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-11-09T13:49:03.494-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"RECOVERY", "id":23987,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger recoveryTimestamp","attr":{"recoveryTimestamp":{"$timestamp":{"t":0,"i":0}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-11-09T13:49:03.497-04:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23134,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Unhandled exception","attr":{"exceptionString":"0xC000001D","addressString":"0x00007FF6CB5BD82A"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-11-09T13:49:03.497-04:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23136,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"*** stack trace for unhandled exception:"}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-11-09T13:49:04.134-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31380,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"BACKTRACE","attr":{"bt":{"backtrace":[{"a":"7FF6CB5BD82A","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/third_party/snappy/dist/snappy.cc","line":887,"s":"snappy::internal::CompressFragment","s+":"BA"},{"a":"7FF6CB5BD5D0","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/third_party/snappy/dist/snappy.cc","line":1717,"s":"snappy::Compress","s+":"2F0"},{"a":"7FF6CB5BDF61","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/third_party/snappy/dist/snappy.cc","line":2167,"s":"snappy::RawCompress","s+":"41"},{"a":"7FF6CB5BE365","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/third_party/snappy/dist/snappy-c.cc","line":42,"s":"snappy_compress","s+":"45"},{"a":"7FF6CB915B8F","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/third_party/wiredtiger/ext/compressors/snappy/snappy_compress.c","line":124,"s":"snappy_compression","s+":"3F"},{"a":"7FF6CB8E6219","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/third_party/wiredtiger/src/log/log.c","line":2548,"s":"__wt_log_write","s+":"159"},{"a":"7FF6CB8F47C6","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/third_party/wiredtiger/src/txn/txn.c","line":1834,"s":"__wt_txn_commit","s+":"2D6"},{"a":"7FF6CB92BE7D","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/third_party/wiredtiger/src/cursor/cur_file.c","line":411,"s":"__curfile_insert","s+":"BDD"},{"a":"7FF6CB8ECD2D","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/third_party/wiredtiger/src/meta/meta_table.c","line":198,"s":"__wt_metadata_insert","s+":"10D"},{"a":"7FF6CB960CFC","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/third_party/wiredtiger/src/schema/schema_create.c","line":998,"s":"__create_table","s+":"4AC"},{"a":"7FF6CB961673","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/third_party/wiredtiger/src/schema/schema_create.c","line":1436,"s":"__schema_create","s+":"443"},{"a":"7FF6CB961BB6","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/third_party/wiredtiger/src/schema/schema_create.c","line":1489,"s":"__wt_schema_create","s+":"36"},{"a":"7FF6CB8C590E","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/third_party/wiredtiger/src/session/session_api.c","line":979,"s":"__wt_session_create","s+":"33E"},{"a":"7FF6CB8B4EBB","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/third_party/wiredtiger/src/session/session_api.c","line":1025,"s":"__session_create","s+":"45B"},{"a":"7FF6CA0A0C7D","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_size_storer.cpp","line":69,"s":"mongo::WiredTigerSizeStorer::WiredTigerSizeStorer","s+":"11D"},{"a":"7FF6CA0C6777","module":"mongod.exe","file":"C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.31.31103/include/memory","line":3417,"s":"std::make_unique<mongo::WiredTigerSizeStorer,__wt_connection * &,std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > &,0>","s+":"47"},{"a":"7FF6CA0C8680","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_kv_engine.cpp","line":625,"s":"mongo::WiredTigerKVEngine::WiredTigerKVEngine","s+":"1C10"},{"a":"7FF6CA08FF31","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_init.cpp","line":135,"s":"mongo::`anonymous namespace'::WiredTigerFactory::create","s+":"6C1"},{"a":"7FF6CA183557","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/db/storage/storage_engine_init.cpp","line":188,"s":"mongo::initializeStorageEngine","s+":"7F7"},{"a":"7FF6C93A9A47","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/db/mongod_main.cpp","line":597,"s":"`mongo::`anonymous namespace'::_initAndListen'::`2'::<lambda_2>::operator()","s+":"77"},{"a":"7FF6C93AC02A","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/db/mongod_main.cpp","line":591,"s":"mongo::`anonymous namespace'::_initAndListen","s+":"B3A"},{"a":"7FF6C93AF41E","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/db/mongod_main.cpp","line":1221,"s":"mongo::`anonymous namespace'::initAndListen","s+":"1E"},{"a":"7FF6C93B27AF","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/db/mongod_main.cpp","line":2224,"s":"mongo::mongod_main","s+":"7BF"},{"a":"7FF6C93969BA","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/db/mongod.cpp","line":41,"s":"wmain","s+":"2A"},{"a":"7FF6CBAF57DC","module":"mongod.exe","file":"d:/a01/_work/43/s/src/vctools/crt/vcstartup/src/startup/exe_common.inl","line":288,"s":"__scrt_common_main_seh","s+":"10C"},{"a":"7FFE8F617374","module":"KERNEL32.DLL","s":"BaseThreadInitThunk","s+":"14"}]}},"tags":[]}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-11-09T13:49:04.141-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF6CB5BD82A","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/third_party/snappy/dist/snappy.cc","line":887,"s":"snappy::internal::CompressFragment","s+":"BA"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-11-09T13:49:04.141-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF6CB5BD5D0","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/third_party/snappy/dist/snappy.cc","line":1717,"s":"snappy::Compress","s+":"2F0"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-11-09T13:49:04.142-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF6CB5BDF61","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/third_party/snappy/dist/snappy.cc","line":2167,"s":"snappy::RawCompress","s+":"41"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-11-09T13:49:04.143-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF6CB5BE365","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/third_party/snappy/dist/snappy-c.cc","line":42,"s":"snappy_compress","s+":"45"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-11-09T13:49:04.143-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF6CB915B8F","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/third_party/wiredtiger/ext/compressors/snappy/snappy_compress.c","line":124,"s":"snappy_compression","s+":"3F"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-11-09T13:49:04.144-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF6CB8E6219","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/third_party/wiredtiger/src/log/log.c","line":2548,"s":"__wt_log_write","s+":"159"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-11-09T13:49:04.145-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF6CB8F47C6","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/third_party/wiredtiger/src/txn/txn.c","line":1834,"s":"__wt_txn_commit","s+":"2D6"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-11-09T13:49:04.145-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF6CB92BE7D","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/third_party/wiredtiger/src/cursor/cur_file.c","line":411,"s":"__curfile_insert","s+":"BDD"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-11-09T13:49:04.146-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF6CB8ECD2D","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/third_party/wiredtiger/src/meta/meta_table.c","line":198,"s":"__wt_metadata_insert","s+":"10D"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-11-09T13:49:04.147-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF6CB960CFC","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/third_party/wiredtiger/src/schema/schema_create.c","line":998,"s":"__create_table","s+":"4AC"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-11-09T13:49:04.147-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF6CB961673","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/third_party/wiredtiger/src/schema/schema_create.c","line":1436,"s":"__schema_create","s+":"443"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-11-09T13:49:04.148-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF6CB961BB6","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/third_party/wiredtiger/src/schema/schema_create.c","line":1489,"s":"__wt_schema_create","s+":"36"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-11-09T13:49:04.149-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF6CB8C590E","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/third_party/wiredtiger/src/session/session_api.c","line":979,"s":"__wt_session_create","s+":"33E"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-11-09T13:49:04.149-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF6CB8B4EBB","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/third_party/wiredtiger/src/session/session_api.c","line":1025,"s":"__session_create","s+":"45B"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-11-09T13:49:04.150-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF6CA0A0C7D","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_size_storer.cpp","line":69,"s":"mongo::WiredTigerSizeStorer::WiredTigerSizeStorer","s+":"11D"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-11-09T13:49:04.151-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF6CA0C6777","module":"mongod.exe","file":"C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.31.31103/include/memory","line":3417,"s":"std::make_unique<mongo::WiredTigerSizeStorer,__wt_connection * &,std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > &,0>","s+":"47"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-11-09T13:49:04.151-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF6CA0C8680","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_kv_engine.cpp","line":625,"s":"mongo::WiredTigerKVEngine::WiredTigerKVEngine","s+":"1C10"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-11-09T13:49:04.152-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF6CA08FF31","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_init.cpp","line":135,"s":"mongo::`anonymous namespace'::WiredTigerFactory::create","s+":"6C1"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-11-09T13:49:04.153-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF6CA183557","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/db/storage/storage_engine_init.cpp","line":188,"s":"mongo::initializeStorageEngine","s+":"7F7"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-11-09T13:49:04.154-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF6C93A9A47","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/db/mongod_main.cpp","line":597,"s":"`mongo::`anonymous namespace'::_initAndListen'::`2'::<lambda_2>::operator()","s+":"77"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-11-09T13:49:04.155-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF6C93AC02A","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/db/mongod_main.cpp","line":591,"s":"mongo::`anonymous namespace'::_initAndListen","s+":"B3A"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-11-09T13:49:04.156-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF6C93AF41E","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/db/mongod_main.cpp","line":1221,"s":"mongo::`anonymous namespace'::initAndListen","s+":"1E"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-11-09T13:49:04.157-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF6C93B27AF","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/db/mongod_main.cpp","line":2224,"s":"mongo::mongod_main","s+":"7BF"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-11-09T13:49:04.157-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF6C93969BA","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/db/mongod.cpp","line":41,"s":"wmain","s+":"2A"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-11-09T13:49:04.158-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF6CBAF57DC","module":"mongod.exe","file":"d:/a01/_work/43/s/src/vctools/crt/vcstartup/src/startup/exe_common.inl","line":288,"s":"__scrt_common_main_seh","s+":"10C"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-11-09T13:49:04.159-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FFE8F617374","module":"KERNEL32.DLL","s":"BaseThreadInitThunk","s+":"14"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-11-09T13:49:04.161-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23132,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Writing minidump diagnostic file","attr":{"dumpName":"C:\\Program Files\\MongoDB\\Server\\8.0\\bin\\mongod.2024-11-09T17-49-04.mdmp"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-11-09T13:49:04.279-04:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23137,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"*** immediate exit due to unhandled exception"}```

